# Determine $P(| \overline{X} - \overline{Y}| > 1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

The distribution of wages (in monetary units) of male workers in a large factory can be considered as N (μ, 4), and that of female workers as N (μ, 5). Two independent samples are drawn, one with 16 men and the other with 16 women. Determine $P(| \overline{X} - \overline{Y}| > 1)$

$\overline{X}={\sum_{i=0}^N{x_i}\over N}$ is a random variable, so we are able to calculate the expected value:

$E[\overline{X}] = E[{\sum_{i=0}^N{x_i}\over N}] = {1 \over N} E[\sum_{i=0}^N{x_i}] = {1 \over N} \sum_{i=0}^N{E[x_i]} $ Since E is a linear function.

Considering that $x_i$ is normally distributed $E[x_i]=\mu$. Then,

${1 \over N} \sum_{i=0}^N{E[x_i]} = {1 \over N} N*\mu = \mu$

In this way, we get $E[\overline{X}] = \mu$ so $\overline{X}$ is also a normally distributed variable.

However, I am not sure on what I am supposed to do next to solve the determining question of this problem, I was wondering if I could get some help.

Comment: You found $E[\bar X]$ and you know it is normally distributed.  What is its variance? What about $\bar Y$?  What about $\bar X - \bar Y$?

Comment: $Var[\overline{X}]$=$Var[{\sum_{i=0}^{N}{x_i} \over N}]=$ ${1\over N² }Var[\sum_{i=0}^{N}{x_i}]$ Since, the variable $x_i$ is a independent variable we may then write:

${1\over N² }Var[\sum_{i=0}^{N}{x_i}]$ =$ {1\over N² } \sum_{i=0}^{N} Var[{x_i}]$. Again, as $x_i$ is normally distributed $Var[x_i]= {\sigma²}$

Therefore, 

$Var[\overline{X}] =  {{\sigma²} \over n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar argument to compute the variance of $\overline{X}$ since the sample is made of independent variables in the following way
$$\text{Var}(\overline{X})=\text{Var}\left( \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{16}x_i}{16} \right)=\frac{16*4}{16^2}=\frac{4}{16}.$$
Moreover, you can compute the mean and variance for $\overline{Y}$ in the same way getting
$$\text{E}(\overline{Y})=\mu\hspace{2mm}\text{  and  }\hspace{2mm}\text{V}(\overline{Y})=\frac{16*5}{16^2}=\frac{5}{16}.$$
Now observe that since both $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are made of linear combinations of independant normal variables, they are also normal variables. Repeating the argument once more with $\overline{X}-\overline{Y}$ you can easily see that
$$\overline{X}-\overline{Y}\sim N\left(0-0,\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{16}\right)=N\left(0,\frac{9}{16}\right).$$
Finally, since you have the distribution of $\overline{X}-\overline{Y}$ you can easily see that

$$P(|\overline{X}-\overline{Y}|>1)=2\left(1-P\left(\frac{(\overline{X}-\overline{Y})-0}{\sqrt{9/16}} < \frac{1-0}{\sqrt{9/16}} \right)\right)=2(1-P(Z<1))\approx 0.182422$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I appreciate your help. Can you please tell me where the number two in the last line come from?

Comment: I think I can see it:


$P[|\overline{X}-\overline{Y}|>1]=P[-1>\overline{X}-\overline{Y}>1]=P[{-1-0\over \sqrt{9\over16}}>{\overline{X}-\overline{Y}-0 \over \sqrt{9\over16}}>{1-0\over \sqrt{9\over16}}]$.

Let ${\overline{X}-\overline{Y}-0 \over \sqrt{9\over16}}=\overline{Z}$

$P[{-1\over{3\over4}} > \overline{Z} > {1\over{3\over4}} ] = \phi({-4 \over 3})+[1- \phi({4 \over 3})] = [1- \phi({4 \over 3})] + [1- \phi({4 \over 3})] = 2 -  2\phi({4 \over 3})=0.1824$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, upvote and accepted your answer!!

Comment: It was exactly that! Glad I could help.